# ¿Porque se detiene mi aplicacion al hacer una consulta en sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Buenas he desarrollado un aplicación con sqlite como base de datos resulta que en el emulador funciona correctamente lo mismo pasa cuando instalo la aplicación a un dispositivo desde el mismo android studio atraves del cable usb, pero cuando generó el apk e instalo en otros dispositivos la aplicación solo permite hacer registro más no deja hacer consultas y mostrarlos en un recycler(esto funciona correctamente en el emulador y el dispositivo cuando se llega instalar por el cable usb) y mi duda es que se debe este problema.

codigo del adptador

```
 public class AdaptadorCa extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorCa.Tienda> implements View.OnClickListener {
private View.OnClickListener listener;


List<BuscarCarrito> datos;
public AdaptadorCa(List<BuscarCarrito> datos){

    this.datos = datos;

}


@NonNull
@Override
public AdaptadorCa.Tienda onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mostrarcarrito,viewGroup,false);
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
    AdaptadorCa.Tienda holder= new AdaptadorCa.Tienda(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdaptadorCa.Tienda tienda, int position) {

    final BuscarCarrito datosp= datos.get(position);
    Double num1=Double.parseDouble(datosp.getCantidad());
    Double num=Double.parseDouble(datosp.getImporte());
    Double res=num/num1;
    tienda.txtnombre.setText(datosp.getNombreproducto());
    tienda.txtprecio.setText("S/"+res);
    tienda.txtunidad.setText(datosp.getCantidad());
    tienda.txttota.setText("S/"+datosp.getImporte());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datos.size();


}
  public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
    this.listener=listener;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (listener!=null){
        listener.onClick(v);
    }
}
public static class Tienda extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView txtnombre,txtprecio,txtunidad,txttota;

    public Tienda(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        txtnombre=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombrecard);
        txtprecio=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.preciocard);
        txtunidad=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cantidadcard);
        txttota=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalcard);
    }
  }
 }
```

codigo de consulta

```
    private void ConsultarCarrito() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = con.getReadableDatabase();
    BuscarCarrito card = null;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM carrito WHERE codtienda='"+cottien+"'",null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        card = new BuscarCarrito();
        card.setCantidad(cursor.getString(0));
        card.setCodcarrito(cursor.getString(1));
        card.setCodtienda(cursor.getString(2));
        card.setNombreproducto(cursor.getString(3));
        card.setCodusuario(cursor.getString(4));
        card.setImporte(cursor.getString(5));
        card.setNombretienda(cursor.getString(6));
        card.setCodproducto(cursor.getString(7));



        datos.add(card);

        Double totalPrice = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i<datos.size(); i++) {

            totalPrice += Double.parseDouble(datos.get(i).getImporte());
            preciofinal.setText(String.format("%.2f", totalPrice));
        }
    }
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
}
```

xml de donde se encuentra el recycler

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/carritof"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout24"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lo1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.48"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"
    />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout24"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/carritof">
```

xml donde se muestran los datos de adaptar

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:background="#63FFFFFF">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="#63FFFFFF"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#63FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#63FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cantidadcard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nombrecard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preciocard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalcard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

logcat

```
2019-06-14 16:31:39.755 15510-15540/com.example.wonvasusuarios 
E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist! 2019-06-14 
16:31:39.757 15510-15510/com.example.wonvasusuarios 
E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size! 2019-06-14 16:31:40.721 15510- 
15678/com.example.wonvasusuarios
E/vndksupport: Could not load vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so from sphal 
namespace: dlopen failed: library "vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so" not 
found.
2019-06-14 16:32:42.477 15510-15510/com.example.wonvasusuarios 
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length 2019-06-14 16:32:42.477 15510-15510/com.example.wonvasusuarios 
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length 2019-06-14 16:32:42.567 15510-15510/com.example.wonvasusuarios 
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length
```

Comment: intentaste depurar en esos dispositivos en los que te da error?

Comment: Le comento tambien estoy trabajando con notificaciones y ocurre que a los dispositivos que depuro no le llegan las notificaciones, así la desisntale la aplicación y la vuelva instalar pero el apk generado.